# Selecting one subdataset when using ModelBuilder in ArcMap for reprojection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, coordinate-system, modis

I'm trying to reproject roughly 500 MODIS images (MOD09GQ) into an Equal Areas Projection. I've been informed that ModelBuilder would be the best way to do this. However, when I set up my model and try to add my data, I can't see any way to select just one subdataset from the HDF data. I just want to reproject the Band 1 data. As such, when I run the model, all of the datasets are also reprojected, including numerical observations etc., resulting in an image which is just geometric patterns of colours.

I'm new to GIS.

Comment: The coordinate system applies to the whole dataset, you would not re-project a single band in a multi-band dataset as nothing would align up.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So basically, it's not possible to reproject subdatasets from HDF files using ModelBuilder?

Comment: If it were me, I would be extracting out that single band to create a separate raster which you could then re-project, leaving the original multi-band dataset as it was. The Make Raster Layer allows you to select specific bands then you would use Copy Raster to save out.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using the wrong tool.
On the MODIS site, they offer the MODIS Swath Reprojection Tool.

If your input is still in the satellite projection, i.e. 
a full rectangular image with Lat and Lon running somewhat diagonally,
use the MRT and the MOD03 Lat/Lon associated with MOD09GQ.

Valid projections are AEA (Albers Equal Area), 
ER (Equirectangular), GEO (Geographic), 
GOODE (Interrupted Goode Homolosine), 
HAMMER (Hammer), ISIN (Integerized Sinusoidal), 
LAMAZ (Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area), 
LAMCC (Lambert Conformal Conic), MERCAT (Mercator), 
MOLL (Mollweide), PS (Polar Stereographic), 
SNSOID (Sinusoidal), TM (Transverse Mercator), 
and UTM (Universal Transverse Mercator).

You'd want Albers or LAMAZ to preserve Equal Area.
You'll need the Standard Parallel and the other parameters.

There is a GUI that you can use for testing, but once
you get the options correct, you can export a script,
which you can use as a template.  You can select particular 
bands within the HDF file.  Do not use the Lat/Lon within
MOD09GQ, stick with the MOD03.  MRT prefers it.

Watch out for the PixelIsPoint vs PixelIsArea designation
of the Lat/Lon coordinates. HDF is UpperLeft Corner, 
GeoTIFF is center of pixel.  Read the docs to see if you need
to do the half-pixel shift or if it is automatic.

Then write a script to individualize your 500 MRT.prm files
with the appropriate names, sizes, output formats, and regions.
Check your disk space and launch them over a three-day weekend.
Should be done by Tuesday when you return.

Then you can import the 500 GeoTIFFs into Arc for further processing.

There are two tools, MRT and MRT-Swath.  Both remove the bow-tie effect.
I'm hazy on the details, but I think Swath is the one you want.  Read the manual.

Tim Szeliga NOAA